# How fast can a system mouse move?

Tags: performance, system, mouse, limit

Is there a limit to how fast a system mouse can move?

I'm playing around with "cliclick" a mac osx library that controls a system mouse. I'm moving the system mouse from 0,0 to 100,100 covering every point in that rectangle. Cliclick lets me set a delay of 20ns per movement. It should cover 10,000 pixels in 200ms, but instead it takes about 3 seconds even if the delay is set to 0.  Is there a limit to how fast a system mouse can move to different points on the screen?

Comment: Seems to be affected by [mouse acceleration](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-in.html) and I suspect the max limit is related to screen refresh rate.